# react-native-gesture-handler occurs so many warnings

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-native-gesture-handler

I installed `react-native-gesture-handler` in React Native Expo app.
And when I start app, it occurs many warnings.
[image]

I tried to uninstall the `react-native-gesture-handler` package and install it using `expo install`, `yarn add` and `npm install`. But it doesn't solve this problem.
Please let me know the solution if someone knows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` in App.js after installing `react-native-gesture-handler` package using `yarn` or `npm`.

Comment: It did'nt work for me using yarn. I think the best way is to use expo install but it does have a warning in the browser